# How to fix toggle img with if statement

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to toggle an image using an `if` statements looking at an array. The code does not seem to work. I have been able to get it working with a button though in another file

```js
var deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52];

function myFunction() {
    deck.shift();
    deck.shift();
    deck.shift();
    deck.shift();

    if (deck[0] == 1) {
      if (document.getElementById("01c")) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "01c.png";
      }
    } else if (deck[0] == 2) {
      if (document.getElementById("01d")) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "01d.png";
      }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">try it</button>
<img src="" id="img" />
```

this is a working example but with out a if statment

```js
function pic1() {
  document.getElementById("img").src = "http://cliparts.co/cliparts/8TG/beG/8TGbeGAAc.png";
}

function pic2() {
  document.getElementById("img").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Playing_card_diamond_9.svg/2000px-Playing_card_diamond_9.svg.png";
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="img" height="50" />
<input type="button" value="Show Picture 1" onclick="pic1()" />
<input type="button" value="Show Picture 2" onclick="pic2()" />
```

Comment: it is most likely the question, what you really want. please add some more information to the question, and have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: on 4 array.shift() .`1,2,3,4` value are removed.The how to match with `deck[0] == 1` & `deck[1] == 2` .add `console.log(deck)` in your end of the `deck.shift()`

Comment: What is expected result? What is purpose of `deck`?

Comment: they is images of cards. when a button is pressed the if statement runs and it should swap the current image to swap with the right image

Comment: Also add `type="button"` to your button to stop some browsers from submitting

Comment: Why use `document.getElementById("01d")`? .Its not found in your html

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the target element in your array? Instead of using

```
var deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, /* ... */];
```

You could use the target of the cards inside of the array, like

```
var deck = ['01a', '01b', '01c', '01d', '02a', '02b', '02c', /* ... */];
```

Usage

```
if (document.getElementById(deck[0])) {
    document.getElementById("img").src = deck[0] + ".png";
}
```